# Find $\lim{v_{n}}$ with $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac{1}{u_{k}+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(u_n): u_1=5, u_{n+1}=\frac{1}{5}(u_n^{2}-u_n+9).$

Find $\lim{v_{n}}$ with $v_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {\frac{1}{u_{k}+2}}$

I cant have any idea for this, I've tried to find $u_n=f(n)$ but failed. Can anyone help me with this problem ? Thank you

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669628/42969 for a very similar question.

Comment: @MartinR thank u so muchhh, and I want to prove $u_n$ is not bounded above. How can I prove it (I can prove $u_n$ is  incresing